# UserProfileChangeRequest setPhotoUri - How is it done?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

If I want to allow the users to upload their own photo from the device:

1. What is the image format required?
2. Image file size?
3. Image dimensions?
4. Where do I upload it to?

Code:

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();
```

Comment: As you might have noticed it is an image **URI**. So it's the URL of wherever you've stored the profile picture. There are no specific size requirements imposed by Firebase Authentication. If you'd like to upload your own profile images, you can consider using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Frank for quick answers.

I wrote some bits on uploading to firebase storage, then tried pasting it here but "not properly formatted as code" was preventing me to upload.